# Android Studio not generating signed APK, despite saying that it successfully did

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

This may seem like a duplicate question, as there are 4 or 5 other exact questions. But I have tried the solutions to every other question like this with no luck.

Basically, I've been successfully generating signed APKs for weeks now, but out of the blue 3 days ago the signed APK is not being generated. **Simply nothing gets generated, even though Android Studio says that it has successfully generated it.**

I am using Android Studio 3.0.

I have tried totally uninstalling/reinstalling AS, I've made sure that both APK option checkboxes are checked during the signed APK generation dialog window.

I have many times restarted Android Studio and my computer, as well as cleaning/rebuilding many times. I do not know what to do from here.

I really need to get an update of my app out to Google Play but I cannot generate the new APK.

Answer (score 1):

The apk is probably being generated but not on the path you expect. Look around the project subdirectories or search for apk using your operating system search tools.

Comment: Thank you!! So, in one of the other similar questions, someone said that it might be in /app/release folder, which I didn't have. But after your comment I searched some more and found it in another folder. If anyone is having similar issues, really just search around in your app's project folder. I'll report this bug.

Comment: Actually, unfortunately it's still not working. There are actually 3 different places it looks like it's generating to, all with different dates. I found the APK generated for 10/21, 10/25, and 10/27, but I can't find the one that I just generated. All of them are in different file locations. This is ridiculous lol.

Comment: @theRealOne could I suggest marking my question as the answer to your original question as it is might help someone else. You have now moved forward in your fauilt finding and are able to raise a new question relating to inconsistencies in the path of the apk.

Comment: I would, but right now, as far as I can tell, this thing isn't being generated anywhere. The last one generated was on 10/27 and there is absolutely nothing being generated anywhere. I'm searching everywhere, but it's just nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue, what you need to do is after migrating a project to **Android studio 3.0**, delete the already generated signed apk in path **/project/app** and generate the signed apk again, you will see a **release** folder in the same directory.

Comment: @theRealOne can you explain the issue more specifically, is there any release folder created on generating signed apk